# What does the function state.tokenize in 'CodeMirror' mean?

Tags: parsing, codemirror

I want to know the function performed by tokenize in codemirror.

Comment: Your question is too vague. There is no public API method named "tokenize". Many of the different languages use either a function named tokenize, or use a reference named "tokenize" that points to a function. Which "tokenize" are you asking about?

Comment: I am talking about the function and the reference present in the xml.js file. The reference is used to point the inText function and one is used like 'var style = state.tokenize(stream,state);'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

codemirror highlights text by calling a tokenizer function, passing it a context ("state"), and a pointer to the current location in the file that needs to be highlighted ("stream"). The job of this function is to advance the stream past the next token, and to return the type of the token. This is described fairly well in the codemirror api documentation here: http://codemirror.net/doc/manual.html#modeapi

In the case of xml.js (which you referenced in a comment), it has multiple tokenizer functions. Depending on the context, it will set the "tokenize" attribute of the state to refer to one of the tokenizer functions. Then it will use whichever function is pointed by by `state.tokenize` to find the next token in the stream.